# Can't boot from Monterey bootable installer, goes to recovery instead

Tags: macos, startup, install, monterey

I've created a bootable installer for MacOS Monterey (on a USB flash drive) using the usual method of downloading the installer and using 'createinstallmedia' within Terminal.  The command appears to complete successfully.  I've done this before with older versions of MacOS and it's worked fine.

However, the installer I created for Monterey is not working properly.  If I startup with the alt-option key and select it, it appears to boot from the USB installer, but my machine boots into recovery mode instead.  Further indication that something is amiss is the fact that (when booted into my existing system) that the USB installer does not appear in System Preferences -> Startup Disk (even though it does appear when starting up with alt-option).

I've searched for this problem, and have tried the following, to no avail:

1. Un-checked the "ignore ownership" box (in Finder -> GetInfo).
2. Gone to the Startup Security Utility, which says that "Firmware password protection is off".
3. Verified that my computer (2017 Macbook Air) is capable of running this OS, and of course that the certificate is not expired.

I'm at my wit's end. I've tried creating a bootable installer of Big Sur and have the exact same issue.

I have an old USB bootable installer (for ElCapitan) that seems to work fine - the machine will boot up with it, although it too does not appear in SystemPrefs->StartupDisk.

It's a new USB 3.1 32GB stick.  I've formatted with "GUID partition map" and "Mac OS Extended (Journaled)".   Here is the 'diskutil' info for it:

```
/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *31.0 GB    disk2
   1:                        EFI ⁨EFI⁩                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS ⁨Install macOS Monterey⁩  30.7 GB    disk2s2
```

For the record, output of the 'createinstallmedia' command ...

```
sudo /Applications/Install\ macOS\ Monterey.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/Monterey\ installer
Password:
Ready to start.
To continue we need to erase the volume at /Volumes/Monterey installer.
If you wish to continue type (Y) then press return: Y
Erasing disk: 0%... 10%... 20%... 30%... 100%
Making disk bootable...
Copying to disk: 0%... 10%... 20%... 30%... 40%... 50%... 60%... 70%... 80%... 90%... 100%
Install media now available at "/Volumes/Install macOS Monterey"
```

Comment: Have you tried another USB stick?

Comment: No.   I'm seeing no indication that it's bad.  I got it in a pair with the one I tried to do BigSur on - and neither works.   I guess it could be something generic.   I don't have any other ones big enough right now.

Comment: I'm now repeating the download and createinstallmedia to see if that does anything.

Comment: Nothing works.  Tried different USB stick.    Couldn't even erase - and yes, I did search for that (69888 error or something).    Reset PRAM.   Nothing.

Comment: Have you tried launching the installer application from the flash drive as opposed to directly booting into the boot picker screen?

Comment: @pion Yes, it starts up, but takes about 5min to do so (before you see the first screen with "Continue").   Then after quitting it, it won't eject, even after 'killall Finder' and no sign of the install app in 'ps -ef' or Activity Monitor.

Comment: @RustyShackleford Why are you quitting it?

Comment: This is a laptop, with only one disk.   I'm booted on that (internal) disk when I run the installer app.  I can't then do an install on the disk I'm booted on, can I ?

Comment: @RustyShackleford I'm confused. In your question you stated that you wrote the macOS Monterey installer onto a USB flash drive. Then, you presumably ran the "Install macOS" app from the newly-written flash drive, which caused your Mac to reboot into the macOS installer which is on that flash drive. What is preventing you from installing from there onto your internal SSD?

Comment: I don't think double-clicking on the installer app (yes, it's on the USB flash drive) causes the Mac to reboot into the installer.   It simply runs the installer like any other app; that's why I was able to quit out of it.

Comment: Ohh ok, we didn’t even get to the reboot. Alright, let’s capture a spindump during the stall. Please follow the instructions I gave in https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/431150/macbook-pro-suddenly-slows-down-with-high-cpu-load/431152#431152

Comment: Ok, bedtime here but thanks for the help.  Will try tomorrow ...

Comment: @RustyShackleford Give me a ping on here when you've done the above investigation, as understanding the cause of the pre-reboot stall might help us understand the reason for not booting into the installer.

Comment: What do you mean by the pre-reboot stall ?

Comment: @RustyShackleford You mentioned that the installer app hangs after you launch it and before it is able to reboot the system.

Comment: Now I'm confused (thanks for your patience).   I thought that when you start the installer app, by double-clicking it when already booted into a "normal" OS, that it isn't supposed to reboot the system (until after it's finished doing the install, if you let it go that far, which I didn't).    Which, you can't install that way if it's a machine with only one disk, no ?

Comment: Or are you saying, just plug in the USB stick with the installer on it (while booted on your internal drive), start the installer and tell it to install on the internal disk, and that'll work ?  If so, what is the point of a bootable installer ?   I thought you couldn't do an install while booted on the drive you intend to install on.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same problem while trying to get Monterey through USB flash drive  installation and resolved this.

To work around this Monterey installation issue:

1. Install the oldest version available and released with the Mac model with an USB stick (Ex: for my MacBook Air 2018 it is Catalina)
2. From the current version (i.e. Catalina) download the next version (i.e. I think it is Big Sur)
3. Create a bootable USB flash drive for this downloaded version.
4. From the current installed system(i.e. Catalina) and without restarting: click on the installer you see in the usb stick to update the current system to the next one. (install it into a new volume if possible).
5. If you installed it into a new volume: Reboot on the new system by continuing pressing the Option button while it restarts and select the volume with the freshly installed version of macOS.
6. Go to step 2.

Do this until you get to Monterey, jumping from one version to another. Some versions can't be installed through USB but the first version seems to be always installable.

---

**Optional**: If this still does not work: Erase all volumes by pressing <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> before you press on the Power button and by using Disk Utils then do a clean install of the previous main system.

Make a volume for each version of macOS with disk utils and when the installer ask for the disk, just select an empty volume so you won't have to repeat it from step 1.